# AngularJS - ng-disabled disables other fields in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, html, firefox

The following code does not work:

```
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="addPost()">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fill in a title" ng-model="title" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fill in a link" ng-model="link" />
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!title">Add a new post</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

In fact, it works, but it does too much. It disables the button when title is empty, which is correct, but it will also disable the first input field (in firefox). In safari this works fine.

The AngularJS module:

```
/* global angular */

var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.posts = [
          {title: "post 1", upvotes: 5},
          {title: "post 2", upvotes: 7},
          {title: "post 3", upvotes: 3},
          {title: "post 4", upvotes: 2},
          {title: "post 5", upvotes: 6}
        ];

        $scope.addPost = function() {
          $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            upvotes: 0,
            link: $scope.link
          });
          $scope.title = "";
          $scope.link = "";
        };
    }]);
```

Is there something I'm missing? If so, why would it work perfectly in all browsers except Firefox?

Demo to the code: http://embed.plnkr.co/rBQOC9RbroQM5E3bbLZy/preview

**UPDATE:**

The bug could not be replicated in Plunker and JSFiddle. Apparently there was a caching issue, forced refresh in Firefox resolved the issue.

Comment: This is one of those impossible issues. The only way to help you if you create a demo of the problem. Otherwise posted code is just fine and works everywhere including Firefox.

Comment: As far as I know, the entire demo is there. Including the symptoms and the code necessary to replicate it. What else do you need?

Comment: you can add a plunk / jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a caching issue, forced refresh in Firefox resolved the issue.